# How to improve the speed of Qemu TCG

Tags: qemu

The user-mode TCG of qemu executes the MIPS program, or debootstrap is very slow to create the MIPS basic image. Is there any way to optimize the efficiency of TCG translation binary?
It takes time to execute debootstrap on the MIPS machine to build the basic image：144 second

It takes time to execute debootstrap on the x86 machine to build the MIPS64el basic image：714 second

Answer (score 1):

As an end-user there is not much you can do: emulation is just a slow process, and there aren't any tuning knobs on QEMU to change aspects of it. If you're using an older QEMU you could try upgrading to a newer one -- there have been some performance improvements over time. (Don't expect miracles, though.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I heard that scratchbox2 can bypass TCG binary translation. Did you know?

Comment: Yes, you can set up a chroot environment like scratchbox2 where some binaries (like /bin/sh, make, gcc) are really host architecture binaries and aren't emulated at all.